# How can you reference the type of the object you are typing in TS?

Tags: typescript

As a basic example, I would like to conditionally type based on the value of the object being typed:

```
type X<Y = self> = Y extends 'a' ? 'a' : 'b'
const x: X = 'a'
```

My use case is more complex. This is for a `Questionnaire`, which has many types of `Question`s. I would like to type each of the `Questionnaire`'s `Question`s based on the `Question['type']`. Here is a simplified version:

```
type Question<TType> = TType extends 'boolean' ? { type: 'boolean' } : { type: 'other' }
type Questionnaire<TQuestionnaire> = {
  [K in keyof TQuestionnaire]: Question<TQuestionnaire[K]['type']>
}
```

The problem is, in order to get the `type`, a circular reference is made, which TS doesn't seem to allow. How can you type based on the object's properties?

Comment: Generally speaking you can't make circular references if those references need to be eagerly evaluated before the compiler can continue.  There's no polymorphic `this` type in anonymous types, so you can't use that.  But I'm afraid I don't understand either use case.  For example, what do you want `X` to evaluate to?  It could be any of `never`, `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"a" | "b"`.  It's like asking the compiler to evaluate whether "this sentence is true" is true or false; it could be either, and it's probably not fair to expect anything reasonable to come out.  And...

Comment: ...I'm also not sure what to think about `Questionnaire` or what you're trying to do.  You could constrain `T extends Record<keyof T, Question<any>>` and express something like what you're saying, but I don't see the point.  Could you spell out your use cases, maybe show some code that uses `Questionnaire` in valid and invalid ways?  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mZak4N) for context.

Comment: Will something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwCoE8AOKA3gFDLJgEQBcyAzmFKAOYkC+JJlhyAigK4QGwAPYgQcYFAgAebMggAPSCAAmdZACUICEVFUyGTEMwA0aDDioA+a8gC8yIsjLIA2gGlkoZAGsIuCIwyNgAurTYnqFuAOTcEDGhCsoQahoxAEYiIgA2EHAgMcgA-E4UVLSZ2XkFRWzItM7xlSJY0HXsQA) help you?

Answer (score -1):

May be [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) will help you

```js
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using code in my example, though. Only types. Looking for a way to define this as a type.